# Implementing distributed objects in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, distributed-objects

I have two Cocoa applications out of which one is a launchd daemon (Foundation tool). I need to call some of the methods in the main application from the daemon. How do I use Distributed Objects here? Can anybody suggest a complete tutorial (except Apple documentations) for this?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/ProgrammingManual/manual_7.html).

Answer (score 0):

My (otherwise pretty out of date now) comp.lang.objective-c FAQ listing includes a question: [How do I forward messages between remote objects?](http://thaesofereode.info/clocFAQ/#cocoa-do) which explains how to do DO and includes a link to some GNUstep documentation on DO.

Comment: I'm already working on them at present. If anymore, please do suggest. Thank you Graham.

Comment: Sorry.7 hours. Can't find even a single, helpful, understandable sample or document. Fed up. Anybody please help. . . .

Comment: @soorya so what parts of DO that those tutorials don't cover do you need? Or what are they not explaining correctly?

Comment: I have the SimpleThreads sample from the apple documents where there are 2 classes. 1-TransferServer(Server) and 2-Controller(Client). As both the classes are in the same application, TransferServer class has been imported in the Controller class. But, in my case, I have 2 different applications, each class in different applications. Now, how do I import one, if I want to?

Answer (score 0):

Much of the documentation on Distributed Objects on the web (in 2016) appears largely out of date and won't even compile on XCode 7.1. Also, @user23743 's answer had a broken link. Here's a [more current (as of 2016) StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36367753/105539) that shows you how to do it now.